# use find to generate a list of files, then use md5sum

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'd like to use find (or something else if that is more appropriate) to generate a file listing of an entire filesystem, except for /proc.  I will the install some software, then run this command again to see what files have changed.

This is what I have tried, with no success:

```
find / -type f  -xdev -exec md5sum {} + > md5sum.txt
```

That hangs on /proc.

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /var/run \) -prune -o -print -type f -exec md5sum {} + > md5sum.txt
```

I get a partial file listing, then a listing of files with an md5sum. (??)

Is there a way to use the updatedb command to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: You get the listing because you used `-print`. Are you sure that the command hangs? Maybe the md5sum just takes so long for the thousands of files. You can add the option `-D search` and/or `-D exec` for debugging. Another debugging aid would be to temporarily replace `md5sum` by `echo`. I'm not sure why you do want a _md5sum_ in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the command is hanging on a file in /sys/kernel/tracing.

I want an md5sum of the regular OS, then will install a custom rpm, and redo the md5sum to see what files have changed during the install. 

Neither the -D search or -D exec seems to work. The echo does and whips through the filesystem. Odd that the md5sum hangs in /sys/kernel/tracing

Comment: What are you searching for in `/sys/kernel`??? AFIK these are virtual files (like `/proc`) and I don't think that it is sane to calculate a MD5 sum there. I would prune the whole `/sys`, and - for the same reason - also `/dev`, otherwise you might run into the same problems there as well. Restrict your calculation to **real** files.

Comment: On the first glance it looks **OK** (though I still doubt that it is **meaningful**), but put code - properly formatted - into your question (you can **edit** your question), not in a comment. Also, I still would use the aforementioned debugging options. They **should** produce some output. BTW, make sure that you put the i.e. `-D exec` **immediately after** the `find` command, before the starting directories. In addition, instead of doing a `>md5sum.txt`, I would do (for debugging) a `| tee md5sum.txt`.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you check out my find command as something is not correct.

find / \( -path /proc -o -path /var/run -o -path /dev -o -path /sys -o path /var/cache \)  -prune -o -type f -exec md5sum {} + > md5sum.txt

Comment: Sorry, edited thecommand while you were answering.  I'll try the -D option